# Aggregate arrays element-wise in presto/athena

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table which has an `array` column. The size of the array is guaranteed to be same in all rows. Is it possible to do an element-wise aggregation on the arrays to create a new array?

For e.g. if my aggregation is the `avg` function then:

```
Array 1: [1,3,4,5]
Array 2: [3,5,6,1]

Output:  [2,4,5,3]
```

I would want to write queries like these:

```
select
  timestamp_column,
  avg(array_column) as new_array
from 
  my_table
group by 
  timestamp_column
```

The array contains close to 200 elements, so I would prefer not to hardcode each element in the query :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by combining 2 lesser known SQL constructs: UNNEST WITH ORDINALITY, and array_agg with ORDER BY.

The first step is to unpack the arrays into rows using[`CROSS JOIN UNNEST(a) WITH ORDINALITY`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest).  For each element in each array, it will output a row containing the element value and the position of that element in the array.

Then you use a standardard `GROUP BY` on the ordinal, and `sum` the values.

Finally, you reassemble the sums back into an array using [`array_agg(value_sum ORDER BY ordinal)`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html).  The critical part of this expression is the `ORDER BY` clause in the `array_agg` call.  Without this the values would be an an arbitrary order.

Here is a full example:

```
WITH t(a) AS (VALUES array [1, 3, 4, 5], array [3, 5, 6, 1])
SELECT array_agg(value_sum ORDER BY ordinal)
FROM (
    SELECT ordinal, sum(value) AS value_sum
    from t
             CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.a) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(value, ordinal)
    GROUP BY ordinal);
```

Comment: I think I read about both of these functions but couldn't put 2 and 2 together. Thanks!

Comment: there is a problem with this though. order by is not supported in Athena: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/arrays-and-aggregation.html

Comment: Did anyone manage to find a variation that actually works with Athena?

Comment: Looks like order by is supported in Athena since v2 engine got released.